# Sub elements of a div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I have a piece of code enclosed with `div` tags and containing some sub elements:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>A hurr</li>
        <li>A durr</li>
        <li>A murrmurr</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now in the tutorial I am reading, in the CSS file he does:

```
#menu {
    width: 550px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-color: #8AD9FF;
        border-radius: 8px;
}
```

And then:

```
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

To change the appearance of the `ul` element.

I assume that this is an older version of CSS since we now use `.menu` not `#menu` and now it doesn't seem to work to type `menu ul { blabla }`

How do I change the appearance of sub element `ul` in todays CSS?

```css
#menu {
    width: 550px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-color: #8AD9FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li>A hurr</li>
  <li>A durr</li>
  <li>A murrmurr</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "#" is for id selector. "." is for class selector. nothing in this concept has changed from *your* old css to *your* todays css!

Comment: Oh, I guess I have misunderstood this concept then. Could you please clarify the difference between an id and a class?

Comment: # in css is known as an id selector and . (period or dot) is known as a class selector. i,e if you give an element id attribute then you could reference it with #, but instead if you want same style for one or more elements then you could give them a class name and access it via dot. eg1: For <div id="eg1"></div> the css selector would be #eg1{border:1px solid red; }. eg2: <div class="eg2"></div> then css selector would be .eg2{border:1px solid green; }. Nothing fancy about it. Its the way css selectors are..

Comment: I can't get this tutorial to work: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/how-to-create-horizontal-navigation-with-css3.html

If I type #menu {blabla} it does nothing. The #menu ul doesn't light up in my notepad++ either.

Comment: an Id should be unique to each element, though some people incorrectly do not follow that rule, a class may be assigned to any number of elements in effect creating a group that will all have the same style applied

Comment: Refer this [Difference b/w ID & CLASS](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: Why do people down vote my post? It was an honest question and I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question, you can do this :

```
.menu ul li {
    //properties
}
```

You just have to replace your #menu by .menu , because you put it as a class in the html code.

Comment: I changed it to id and this displays nothing:

 <div id="menu">
 <ul>
 <li>A hurr</li>
 <li>A durr</li>
 <li>A murrmurr</li>
 </ul>
 </div>

CSS:

#menu {
width:550px;
height:35px;
font-family:Tahoma,Geneva;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:3px 2px 3px #333333;
border-radius:8px;

#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

Comment: you forgot to close your #menu